# Converting XML image path to image using JQuery

Tags: jquery, html, xml

I am trying to convert a path to image to an actual image when I read in the XML file on my website. The structure of my XML is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding=UTF=8?>
    <peopleNetwork>
     <person id="1">
      <name>Alice</name>
      <friend>Ruby</friend>
      <image>images/ruby.jpg</image>
     </person>
     <person id="2">
      <name>Tom</name>
      <friend>Katty</friend>
      <image>images/ketty.jpg</image>
     </person>
    </peopleNetwork>
```

This is how I am reading in the XML on my page:

```
$("#container").append($(xmlDoc).find('person[id="1"]').text() + '<br/>')
```

What the above code line does is currently reads in all information for person one and displays it in text format, like so:

Alice   Ruby    images/ruby.jpg

What I would like to do is convert the image path to an actual image, searching online I was able to write this code:

```
<img src"images/' +$(this).find("image").text() + '"alt=$(this).find('person[id="1"]').text()>);
```

I am not sure how I can put these together, I am fairly new and tried playing around with it but failed at each attempt - any help would be appreciated, let me know if I was not clear enough.

EDITED:I wrote this:

```
$("#container").append('<div class"peopleNetwork"><img src="images/' + $(xmlDoc).find("image").text() + alt="' + $(xmlDoc).find('person[id="1"]').text())
```

I am not sure if this is correct or not but when I run my website it gives this error

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment
```

Answer (score 0):

You just needed to create a `<img>` tag within your `.append()` statement.

```js
$.ajax({
 type: "GET",
 url: "./peopleNetwork.xml",
 datatype: "xml",
 success: function(xml){
  var xmlDoc = $.parseXML(xml),
  $xml = $(xmlDoc);
  $xml.find("person").each(function(){
   var image = $(this).children("image").text();
   $("#container").append($(this).children("name").text() + " " + $(this).children("friend").text() + " " + '<img src="./' + image + '">' + "<br />");
  });
 }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
</div>
```